# foreach loop in tcsh using afni program

Tags: linux, shell, unix, foreach, terminal

I use a program called AFNI at work, and none of us are programmers, but we have enough knowledge to get by more often than not. Usually, when we have a lot of files we want to run AFNI on, we have to copy and paste the commands and edit the filenames in notepad before copying it into terminal, and this can elicit a number of mistakes. We are attempting to streamline this by using a shell script.

I am trying to run a foreach loop on a folder with .nii files in it, and I want those filenames to be appended to the end of the line that begins with '3dclustsim.' I want the filename to be put where $name is, so that the command is executed on that file.

So far, I have:

```
#!/bin/tcsh

clear
set path = ($path /home/lab/abin)
afni


foreach name (`*.nii`)
    3dclustsim -fwhmxyz 16 16 16 -pthr 0.05 0.01 0.005 0.001 -athr 0.05 -nodec -iter 10000 -OKsmallmask -mask /home/lab/Desktop/Masks/$name
end
```

I have had no luck with any iteration of the above, or any modification I have found online. I am aware of the disdain many people have for C shells, but this program will only run in tcsh on a Unix/Linux/Mac machine in terminal.

If there is anything else I need to provide, please let me know.

Comment: I realized I forgot to provide the error I receive:
    *.nii: No match.

Comment: For future reference, you can edit your posts by clicking on the `edit` at the bottom.

Comment: `#!/bin/tcsh` should be `#!/bin/tcsh -f`. Without the `-f`, it will waste time executing your startup files (`.tcshrc` or whatever) -- and worse, the script might *depend* on something in your startup files, which means the script won't be usable by anyone else. Why do you execute `clear` at the top of the script? I might have useful information on my terminal screen; if I want to clear it, I can type Ctrl-L myself. The backticks are the real problem, but if you get `*.nii: No match` then there aren't any such files in your current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Try adding/replacing this

```
cd /path/to/dir/with/nii_files
/bin/ls -l *.nii

foreach name ( * ) 
     3dclustsim -fwhmxyz 16 16 16 -pthr 0.05 0.01 0.005 0.001 -athr 0.05 -nodec -iter 10000 -OKsmallmask -mask /home/lab/Desktop/Masks/$name
end
```

Your `afni` program may be reading a config file that tells it where to put the files. You have to `cd` to the correct directory to process them.

You may be doing that correctly, but that you get an error message `*.nii : No Match` is telling  you that the files you want to process aren't there.

However the confusing part of your question is that you have surrounded your `*.nii` in back-quotes (in the for loop). Back-quotes mean "find the closing back-quote and then take the enclosed string and execute it as a command. If you really had no files in that dir, you should see something like

```
 foreach name (`nonesuch`)
 nonesuch : Command not Found.
```

But, that said, if you use the `cd` and `ls`, you can prove to yourself that you're in the right directory, and then the files should be procecssed.

Also, if you are creating this script with a windows editor, and then executing on Unix/Linux, you'll need to

```
dos2unix ./myScript.sh
chmod 755 ./myScript.sh
#then you can run it
./myScript.sh
```

IHTH

Comment: Afni is in 'abin' which is why I have to direct the terminal to it before I can open it. Can I still cd to a directory after doing that and expect afni to function properly?

Comment: Given standard practices and NO config file with an overriding DATAOUT_DIR (or similar), 1. you have abin in the PATH variable, so you can run the program from any directory. 2. If you haven' done a `cd /some/otherdir` before you launch `afni`, then the files should be in the same dir. I'm encouraging you to use std system tools like `/bin/ls -l *.nii`. If you get a message "no files found", then you have to figure out where `afni` is putting the file, maybe its in the documentation, maybe you have to ask another `afni` user, or if you know that there is a config file, look there. Good luck!